# Interaction between UserControl and Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, window

I've created a UserControl which contains some conrols (buttons and checkboxes).

After that I added a reference to that UserControl in my WPF Windows.

What I want to do is : when I click in a button in the UserControl this button fires an action and change something in the Windows (Textbox1.Text = "something").

My problem is that I can't access to controls inside the Windows from the UserControl.

Any help please ?

`EDIT` : Added code sample

```
<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="Project.Temp.MainSurface"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"              
                 Title="Project.Temp"
>
<Grid x:Name="Root" ... >
     <Grid x:Name="Child" ... >
         <local:MyUserControl x:Name="UserControlStart" ... />
     </Grid>
...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to approach this "communication"...here are just some of the ways...there are plenty more:

1) Define a Command...which your button will raise when it is clicked.

Then in your Window you will handle that command, and change the TextBox to some string.

You can use a CommandParameter if you want to provide some data/context.

2) Define a RoutedEvent (bubbling one) which bubbles up the tree and a Window can then handle it. The event would be raised by your Button in the UserControl and would contain the "text" you wanted to be set in the Window.

3) If your "something" is kind of a "state" indicator...then you could provide a "state" property on your UserControl (or another option have a ViewModel which contains the state data instead). Then your TextBox could bind to that property on your UserControl (or ViewModel) to obtain the "state" (either as a value which then is "converted" into a displayable message with a converter, or as a direct string).

Answer (score 1):

UserControl shouldn't be able to change Window related stuff because UserControl is independent entity.

Expose an event in USerControl and handle that event in Window. In that event do what you want to your Window

Answer (score 0):

When you create the usercontrol you have to pass a handle to your main window. Then you have to create public methods in the main window that you call from the user control and that change the value in the textbox.

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the instance of the usercontrol? And what is the name of the main window?

Comment: A user control should in no way depend on the type of its owner.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, without having any knowledge about the owner the user control cannot interact with it...

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added some code, can you point me how to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not going to write it all out. 1) add an `event` or an `ICommand` property to the UserControl. 2) Bind to either one from the Window.